# Average return from rolling two 10-sided dice

Tags: probability, expected-value

I'm going to roll TWO 10-sided dice (sides labeled 1-10) and pay you the sum of the two rolls. On average, how much money would you be paid?

intuitively I thought the highest value I could be paid is 20 which results from 10 on the first die and 10 on the second die. And the lowest value would be 2. So on average I will be paid the average of them which is $$E=\frac{20+2}{2} = 11$$

If this is the correct answer, how to mathematically prove that. What is the formula?

Answer (score 0):

No. You have to calculate the following:

$$\sum_{i=2}^{20} i \times (\text{probablility of obtaining the sum i}).$$

This will give your answer.

---

You don't need to manually calculate the probability of obtaining the sum $i$ for each $i$. Consider the set $$A_i=\{1,2,...,i-1\}.$$ Note that $i=1+(i-1)=2+(i-2)=\cdots.$

The couplets $(1,i-1),(i-1,1),(2,i-2),(i-2,2),...$ correspond to the sum $i.$ For even $i,$ we have $$2(\frac{i-1}2)=i-1$$ many couplets giving the sum $i$ and for odd $i,$ we have $$2(\frac i2 - 1)+1=i-1$$ many couplets giving the sum $i$. That means it doesn't matter whether $i$ is even or odd.

Comment: Thanks I listed the probability of obtaining the sum i for each number between 2 and 20 but that took time and the result was also 11. Is there a way to know the probability of obtaining the sum i without having to list all the combinations manually because it takes so much time which I usually don't have during the exam.

Comment: There's a property called "linearity of expectation" which states "the expectation of the sum is the sum of the expectations". So E(D10 + D10) = E(D10) + E(D10). Now we're back to uniform probability in each term, so your average of min + max works: E(D10) = (10 + 1)/2 = 5.5, so the expectation of the sum is twice that, 11.

Comment: @MoazNasem I have edited my answer.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, kindly mark it as the best.